# How to specify multiple schedulers on the kernel boot command line?

Tags: grub2, io, kernel-parameters, nvme

We have systems with both spinning mechanical disks, and NVME storage. We want to reduce the CPU overhead for IO by taking any IO scheduler out of the way. We want to specify this on the Linux boot command line; i.e. in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, in the file `/etc/default/grub`.

- For mechanical disks, we can append `elevator=noop` to the command line. This  corresponds to the `noop` value in `/sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler`
- For NVME storage, we instead use `none` in `/sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler`; which presumably (could not confirm) can be specified at boot time by appending `elevator=none`.

This becomes a two-part question:

1. Is `elevator=none` the correct value to use for NVME storage in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`?
2. Can both values be specified in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`?

If the second is correct, I'm guessing that `elevator=noop` will set correctly for the spinning disks, but the NVME controller will gracefully ignore it; then `elevator=none` will set correctly for NVME disks, but the spinning disk controller will gracefully ignore *that*.

Comment: Thanks -- You may as well put that up as the answer. And the answer to the "headline" question is "you don't".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I/O schedulers are assigned *globally* at boot time.
Even if you use multiple `elevator=[value]` assignments only the last one will take effect.
To automatically/permanently set per-device schedulers you could use [`udev` rules](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance#Changing_I.2FO_scheduler), [`systemd` services](http://www.pellegrino.link/2014/07/16/changing-the-io-scheduler-on-a-specific-disk.html) or configuration & performance tuning tools like [`tuned`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/chap-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-tuned).
As to your other question, the answer is yes, `elevator=none` is the correct value to use for NVME storage.

Comment: I like the simplicity of the systemd approach, very similar to rc.local, but those only work for existing attached devices. The udev method will also work for removable disks.

Comment: @Rich - yup, `udev` rules rule (pun intended).